# SignalR Hub method keeps going even after browser is closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I have a method that loops over a series of elements, and adds some stuff to a database. I am using SignalR to post real-time progress of this from the server to the client. That all works fine.

However, when I close the browser and/or hit the 'Stop Debugging' button that method keeps going on in the background! I can tell because when I query the database, it is still adding records and when I launch the project it will trigger any server-side breakpoints immediately - even though this method is not called in the startup.

If I ran the code

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
     do stuff with i
}
```

and then hit stop halfway through, I'd expect it to stop. But SignalR seems to continue until it reaches 1000, even if I've hit stop and closed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a real-time communication framework, and this means that it's not like a HTTP request where Web browser starts a request, server receives it, client waits until server processes the requests and sends a requests, and finally the connection is closed (HTTP is a stateless protocol).

If you close your Web browser while some operation is done in the server-side and this operation was started using SignalR, the operation won't end. You'll need to send *heartbeats* from the server while it's doing the long running operation and if some of the *heartbeats* aren't answered by the client, your server code will cancel it.

*Heartbeats* are like *pings*. It's just about sending a *hello* and excepting an *I'm here!* message from the client in time intervals.